# Lightbox 2.6 positioning

Tags: css-position, lightbox

I cannot figure out how to customize the positioning of my lightbox images. I'd like it to remain in a fixed position relative to the top and left side of the page. I can move it in the css but not without also moving other contents (such as the close button, the border, titles, etc). I've read posts saying to change the .js file but I don't see any of the quoted text in my .js file. I assume the script is different in version 2.6? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in line 136 replace with this:

```
var hlight = this.$lightbox.height();
top = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 2) - ( hlight / 2);
```

This center in window

https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js